# Is georeference the same as geotransform?

Tags: gdal, ogr, coordinate-system

Does georeference mean the same as geotransform?  If not then what is the difference?

Comment: In what context? Where have you read "georeference" and "geotransform"?

Comment: I am following a thread showing how to open a DEM with GDAL/OGR Python module. In the thread the author uses the command GetGeoTransform.  But I am struggling to know what the significance of it is.  Is the output from GetGeoTransform a bunch of parameters that are used in the georeferencing process?

Comment: According to http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668 yes, GetGeoTransform returns a bunch of parameters, `for transforming between pixel/line (P,L) raster space, and projection coordinates (Xp,Yp) space`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Georeferencing is used to add space-related information to a data set
- Geotransformation is just the change of the projection you are working with

I dont really understand your edit. This is just a definition I am not sure if you were searching that?

Comment: Rouven: Your definition of georeferencing is correct but very broad. To link the two, which may help the OP, georeferencing usually requires a (geo)transform. In til_b's example, to properly reference an image, it must be transformed into map space.